# HttpContext.Current.Session equivalent in Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, httpsession

I'm an asp.net developer and I'm now working on a Spring MVC webproject.

I want to write a helper class that allows me to get the current User or check if a user is logged in, something like that.

In asp.net I could create a class anywhere in my project and for accessing the current session for a request I could write `HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"]`.

What is the way to do this in Spring MVC?

I found this Blogpost, saying that this is not possible ([here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/284309/JSP/java/Current-Request-Object-Servlet)). But I also found this stackoverflow post, where the method of getting the current session looked pretty similar to the asp.net way ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712482/is-there-a-way-to-inject-httpsession-with-spring-in-jsf-application)). It didn't work for me though.

Comment: Do you use Spring Security, too?

Comment: No, I didn't know that. Looks interesting. But I will need this Session thing for more stuff, not just Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring MVC/Spring Security you can make use of the [`AuthenticationPrincipal`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-authentication-principal) annotation which resolves given argument to the current authenticated user.

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public String show(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUser customUser) {
    // do something with CustomUser
    return "view";
}
```

Under the hood current authentication is fetched from the SecurityContext:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

You can use `SecurityContextHolder` to retrieve current authentication anywhere in your code. But keep it to a bare minimum in order to keep clarity and testability high.

If you want to retrieve or write data from/to the current http session just instruct Spring MVC to give it to you:

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public String show(HttpSession session) {
    // do something with session data
    session.getAttribute("myAttr");
    return "view";
}
```

If you want to save data in the session for several request, for instance a wizard, you can leverage Spring's so called [`SessionAttributes`](http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.de/2011/01/spring-mvc-session-attributes-handling.html).